# How to add dictionaries inside of a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to connect separated messages of a chat, so I created a list for all the dictionaries

```
messages = ["Hello", "How you doing","fine","how can I help you", "how to do this?", "like this", "thanks","man","no problem"]
Person1= [True,True,False,False,True,False,True,True,False]

data =[]

chat_messages = messages
people = Person1
k = 0

for i in range(len(messages)):
    if people[i] == people[i+1]:
        chat_messages[i+1] = chat_messages[i] +" " +chat_messages[i+1]
        chatData  = {'text': chat_messages[i+1], 'person1': people[i]}
        data[k] = chatData 
    else:
        k +=1
        chatData = {'text': chat_messages[i+1], 'person1': people[i+1]}
        print(chatData )
        data[k] = chatData 
       
print(data)
```

I'm getting errors in here

```
  File "main.py", line 20, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    data[k] = chatData  
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

How can I fix it please?
I want the output of data to look like this:

```
data = [{'text': 'Hello How you doing', 'person1': True} , {'text': 'fine how can I help you', 'person1': False}, {'text': 'how to do this?', 'person1': True}]
```

Comment: `data.append(chatData)`…?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: I'm very sorry it's part of a machine-learning project I forgot it's not clear from the question

Comment: I need the value of k when storing the correct message because it can be overwritten

Answer (score 0):

You cant add elements to a list in python this way. you have to use python method append().

```
data.append(chatData)
```

This method will add elements at the end of the list.
You can learn more python list methods using this link
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/list-methods-python/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you add the index i + 1, it gives an error when you get to the nr 9, because your list index stops at 8. Here is my solution:

```
messages = ["Hello", "How you doing","fine","how can I help you", "how to do this?", "like this", "thanks","man","no problem"]
Person1= [True,True,False,False,True,False,True,True,False]

data =[]

chat_messages = messages
people = Person1
k = 0
data = []
for i, msg in enumerate(messages):
    try: 
        if people[i] == people[i+1]:
            chat_messages[i+1] = chat_messages[i] +" " +chat_messages[i+1]
            data.append({'text': chat_messages[i+1], 'person1': people[i]})
    except: 
        pass
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
messages = ["Hello", "How you doing","fine","how can I help you", "how to do this?", "like this", "thanks","man","no problem"]
Person1= [True,True,False,False,True,False,True,True,False]

data =[]

chat_messages = messages
people = Person1
k = 0

for i in range(len(messages)):
    if len(messages)-1 is i:
        None
    else:
        if people[i] == people[i+1]:
            chat_messages[i+1] = chat_messages[i] +" " +chat_messages[i+1]
            chatData  = {'text': chat_messages[i+1], 'person1': people[i]}
            data.append(chatData)
        else:
            chatData = {'text': chat_messages[i+1], 'person1': people[i+1]}
            print(chatData )
            data.append(chatData)

       
print(data)
```

Comment: It would be really helpful you could add some explanations on what you did different and how it helped/solved the user's issues.